# swift 3.1 cannot pass decimals from UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, double

in my View Controller I have a uitextfield where user can input decimals for some expense by pressing add button. 
The issue: if I input Int like "100" everything works properly, but if I input "12,3" data is not accepted even if I'm converting the text in a Double
note : if I input a decimal, "print 1" values and stop, just like no data was set
note2: in my textfield I set to no correction and spellchecking due to xcodebug about textfield keyboard, but this change does not seem to influence the present issue

I declare:

```
var amount : Double!
```

my button:

```
@IBAction func addBillButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("button pressed 1")

    guard self.dataInput.text != nil else {return}
    amount = Double(self.dataInput.text!)
    guard amount != nil else {return}
    print("amount       : \(amount!)")


    dateShowed = myDatePicker.date as NSDate!
    let dateShowedString = convertDateToString(dateToConvert: dateShowed as NSDate)
    print("date         : \(dateShowedString)")


    if presentPickName != nil {
        print("name is  : \(presentPickName!)")
    } else {
        print("presentPickName is nil")
    }


    //        guard presentPickData != nil else {return}
    if presentPickTag != nil {
        print("tag is       : \(presentPickTag!)")
    } else {
        print("presentPickData is nil")
    }

    //func for saving in core data
//        saveExpense(amountToSave: amount, amountDate: dateShowed as NSDate, owner: presentPickName, tag: presentPickTag)

    resetViewForNextInput()

    self.dataInput.resignFirstResponder()


    print("button pressed 2")

 }
```

my textfield in storyboard

[image]

EDIT SOLUTION:

in my button

```
    guard let stringFromTxtField = self.dataInput.text else {return}
    print(stringFromTxtField)
    let myFormatter = NumberFormatter().number(from: stringFromTxtField) as! Double
    print(myFormatter)
    amount = myFormatter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on locale, passing directly from text to number and viceversa should always be done by using a `NumberFormatter`. The number formatter knows the locale set in the settings and convert correctly your number.
For instance in italy decimal places are displayed with a `,`,italian users find natural to input number like these 1,5 or 54,2 swift `Double` prints decimal like this 1.5 54.2 because the programming language requires numbers with a US format.
Thus a `Double` is not able to parse the string because it expect a number in this format.

Using a `NumberFormatter`you can pass from the text to a correct number number because it know from the locale that the decimal separator in italy is `,`.
Of course number formatters has a plenty of options, forcing the locale, forcing the decimal separator etc.

```
let double = NumberFormatter().number(from: "1,3") as! Double
```

This line of code with a locale set to Italy will get correctly a number of 1.3

Comment: great explanation!  but How should I implement it in my code?

Comment: @biggreentree using a NumberFormatter as I wrote

Comment: I'm not that expert, I added a possible solution un my update, could you check were I'm wrong?

Comment: now it should work, If you can give me some advice for optimizing it it would be nice, thanks for you solution

Comment: @biggreentree there is no optimization, now it should be fine, if you want to be totally safe it would be better to make the car as an optional and unwrap the value. Like this: `guard let double = NumberFormatter().number(from: "1,3") as? Double else { return }  
 amount = double`.  and delete your guard statement. if the cast is correct amount is set to the value of double. if not it simply returns